# how to give different linespecs for a plot of matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot

I have matrix and I'd like to plot each line of it with a different linespec:

```
linespec = {'b.', 'r-', 'g--o','+','x','*','o','.'};
h=plot(myMatrix');
[row,col]=size(myMatrix); //row can be max. 8
for i=1:row
   set(h(i),'LineStyle','-','Marker',linespec{i});
end
```

Above code, I get error;

> > Error using set
> >
> > Bad property value found.
> >
> > Object Name: line
> >
> > Property Name: 'Marker'

Can someone tell me the proper way to accomplish it? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried it and it worked. Maybe the problem is in your Matrix? Can you post part of it? EDIT: nevermind, I got the error now... checking it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround you can change the Marker Type in the loop as you plot each row, since you can provide a 3rd argument to `plot` which specifies the line style,, marker symbol and color:

```
clc
clear


M = rand(8);

linespec = {'b.', 'r-', 'g--o','+','x','*','o','.'};

[row,col]=size(M);
hold all
for i=1:row
    h(i) =plot(M(i,:),linespec{i});

end
```

Output:

[image]

As for the reason behind the error, [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/92393-why-do-i-get-an-error-when-setting-the-linestyle-property-for-multiple-lines-in-matlab-7-4-r2007a) page from the MathWorks explains that since R2010a:

> You can not set the LineStyle and Marker properties simultaneously.
>   You have to call the SET function twice [...]

So something like this would work:

```
clc
clear


M = rand(4);

linestyles = {'-', '-.', '--',':'};
markers = {'.','>','o','+'};
colors = {'b','r','g','k'};

h = plot(M)

for i = 1:size(M,1)
set(h(i), 'LineStyle', linestyles{i})
set(h(i), 'Marker', markers{i})
set(h(i), 'Color', colors{i})

end
```